# fixed length circular buffer in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to create a fixed length circular buffer of some general type in Haskell.  The items in the buffer need to be located one after another in physical memory (not linked list).  I want this specific structure because it will improve the chances of all the data getting to the L2 cache on the CPU together.  I have read about how Haskell allows for new data types, however it looks like types created using "data" are little more that glorified c structs with pattern matching and associated methods.  Is it possible to create low level data structures like the one described above completely in Haskell.

Comment: It is difficult to have low-level reasoning in Haskell. IMHO, it is better to use C for tasks where you want to squeeze out the last drops of performance.

Comment: I wonder how [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) would compare to such a data structure.

Comment: jaspervdj, sclv, Dan Burton, thanks for the answers.  I am not sure what is the best answer yet, but I will be researching everything you guys suggested.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Dan Burton: oddly enough, I tested this not long ago.  Using Data.Sequence was generally the best performing option, and (very surprisingly) often outperformed an unboxed mutable array.  Even in pathological cases (lots of reads from the middle of the sequence), performance wasn't that much worse than the mutable buffer.  I was so surprised by this result I'm still not sure that I believe it, but I don't think I made any mistakes in my testing.

Comment: @John L: you should write a blog post on your findings. I, for one, would read it.

Comment: @Dan Burton: done.  http://johnlato.blogspot.com/2011/07/circular-buffers.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want a mutable array-like structure, and you particularly want an *unboxed* one so that the underlying array stores not only pointers to your data, but the items themselves.

Data.Array from the standard array library gives you a version of that, but especially high-performance arrays are available from the vector library: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector

The vector library, like ByteString, Text, and a few others, uses a fair amount of low-level ghc-specific primitives under the hood. To just use the library, you shouldn't have to worry about such things yourself. But if you decide that the library doesn't give you what you need, then you can also learn a fair amount in the way of tricks and techniques by reading through its source code for yourself.

Comment: Another nice feature with Data.Vector is that it's relatively simple to pass `Data.Vector.Storable` arrays to a C library.

Comment: see hackage package `vector-buffer`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is certainly possible. The chapter [creating a bloom filter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/advanced-library-design-building-a-bloom-filter.html) from [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) should be a very good example for these kinds of implementations.